PipeWire with Allen & Heath Qu-16 on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
An unfortunate upgrade (downgrade?) from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS broke my audio input from an Allen & Heath Qu-16 digital mixer. I've been using OBS Studio (several versions, now 30.2.3) with no issues. My OBS audio source is the USB audio output from the Qu-16. This has been working great in OBS with the Qu-16 USB audio as a PulseAudio source.
After the Ubuntu upgrade, stutter and noise on the audio input with PulseAudio is awful. I have made numerous attempts to configure a PipeWire audio source for the Qu-16, without success. Other plug-and-play analog-to-USB audio converters are readily configured as PipeWire audio sources in OBS. I need to use the USB digital output from the Qu-16.
Has anyone found a configuration that works for PipeWire and an Allen & Heath Qu-16 USB audio input to OBS?

Not a solution but a workaround if it's Pipewire causing the issues - you can just switch back to Pulseaudio. I could not get surround sound passthrough to work with Kodi under Pipewire so i just switched back to Pulseaudio. I am sure you can find details online how to do it, if not I can post an answer with what I did anyway.

@codlord I would welcome your posted answer and thank you for your offer. I am willing to try it. The Pulseaudio source (Qu-16 USB) that I am using is causing terrible stutter and noise.

I did this:
systemctl --user mask pipewire-pulse.service pipewire-pulse.socket
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire.service pipewire.socket
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire-media-session.service
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire pipewire-pulse
sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio

And sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
And commented out the line:
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
Then pulseaudio -k to restart pulseaudio.
I am not really sure on the difference between mask vs disable on services (e.g. I don't know why I am masking some services and disabling others, it's just commands I found online elsewhere - but so far it has worked for me).
If you have problems or it does not work for you it should be easy enough to reverse the commands/order of commands to enable/disable/mask/unmask as appropriate.
